# selection list of numbers from a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a integer variable `:quantity` in a model. 
How would I make a selection list that goes from 1 to the number in that variable?
Do I need to somehow make a separate array of numbers to call for the selection list?, or is there an easier way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[0..quantity].each.do |q|
  # selection item
end
```

Additionally, you could try defining a derived property in the model:

```
def quantity_items
  [0..quantity]
end
```

You might be able to use the Rails helpers if you do that.